# Links work in chrome but not firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

So i'm doing an assessment for school and long story short one of the requirements is that your website has to work in two browsers (Chrome and Firefox). My pages work fine in both but my navigation buttons only work in chrome and returns the error "protocol (h) is not associated with any program or is not allowed in this context" when i use test them in Firefox. It also gives me a tip saying I might need to install other software to open this address.

My code is below.

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="H:/documents/200dts/web_design/scoville_scale/index.html">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        Content
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="H:/documents/200dts/web_design/scoville_scale/pages/scoville_scale.html">The Scoville Scale</a>
            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">About Us</a>
    <a href="#">Gallery</a>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS.

```
/* Navigation Bar */
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    background-color: #2f040c;
}

#menu a {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; 
}

#menu a:hover {
    color: grey;
} 

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #2f040c;
    min-width: 80px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: grey;
    padding: 16px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {   
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to append the path to the document with `file:///` like so:

```
href="file:///H:/documents/200dts/web_design/scoville_scale/pages/scoville_scale.html"
```

Check out the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/at1r6ev5/1/), and the Wikipedia page on [File URI Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

[This question](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/963224) on support.mozilla.org may also be of use to you

---

The reason it said `protocol(h)` does not exists, is because it thought the drive letter was a [protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) (like `http`, `https` and `ftp`).

So it thought that `H:/` was another way of accessing data via the internet.

Comment: @CaramelPanda No problem! If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted (press the green tick underneath the voting buttons).

Answer (score 0):

if this page put in index.html directory,
Try this.

```
 <a href="index.html">Home</a>
 ....
 <a href="pages/scoville_scale.html">The Scoville Scale</a>
```

it is not,

```
 <a href="file:///H:/documents/200dts/web_design/scoville_scale/index.html">Home</a>
  ....
 <a href="file:///H:/documents/200dts/web_design/scoville_scale/pages/scoville_scale.html">The Scoville Scale</a>
```